# Polymorphism Terminology

Tags: polymorphism, computer-science

I've looked and I've looked, and can't find the academic answer I'm looking for.

If a method is polymorphic:

```
public class Widget
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void doSomething(int fizz)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

... then `doSomething` can be said to be a *polymorphic method* of class `Widget`.  I am looking for the academic/mathematical term to use when referring to the different varieties of a polymorphic method.  For instance, in chemistry you have the concept of *isotopes* which are variants of atoms that simply have different numbers of neutrons.  I want to be able to say that `doSomething(int)` is an *x* of `doSomething()`, much like Tritium is an isotope of Deuterium.

**What's the correct terminology for two methods that are polymorphs of one another....just polymorphs? Polymorphic conjugates??!?**

I know that somewhere, somebody knows the answer to this.

Comment: The term "polymorphic method" has special meaning in many languages, and [may not refer to overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236128/polymorphism-terminology/7236159#7236159). Use with caution.

Comment: But beware: Java does not support multi-polymorphism/multi-methods, i.e. overloaded methods aren't dispatched dynamically, but the static type decides which method is chosen. If you want multi-polymorphism in Java, you can use the java multimethod framework (http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~forax/works/jmmf/), but it uses reflection heavily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Overloaded method`. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading) wiki article.

**Updated:**
*how do I refer to doSomething(int) from the context of doSomething()*
In languages like C++/C#/Java it is common pattern:

```
public class Widget
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // ...
        int default = 42;
        this.doSomething(default);
    }

    public void doSomething(int fizz)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Widget in this case has an overloaded method. But my question is how do I refer to doSomething(int) from the context of doSomething()? I can't say that doSomething() has an overloaded method of doSomething(int), the same way I can say Tritium is an isotope of Deuterium.

Comment: @Mara "doSomething(int) is an overloaded method of doSomething()"

Comment: @Mara Updated answer. I hope I've correctly understand what you want.

Comment: Yep! For some reason I didn't know that it was alright to call one method an overload of another method; I thought it was only correct to say that some class has 1+ overloaded methods. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, that's definitely not what you meant :)  
But @rlb.usa is completely right.